# CSS a:hover border-bottom length

Tags: html, css, text, border, underline

Could anyone help me out by telling me why the `a:hover { border-bottom: 2px; }` continues on over the length of the link itself?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", "Times", "serif";
}

header {
    background-color: #191919;
    padding: 56px;
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    display: inline;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    color: #ffffff;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 28px;
    width: 135px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ac9962;
    font-size: 18px;
}

a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ac9962;
    font-size: 18px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet2.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
         <nav>
        <ul>
           <a href="www.youtube.com"><li>Menu 1</li></a>
           <a href="www.youtube.com"><li>Menu 2</li></a>
           <a href="www.youtube.com"><li>Menu 3</li></a>
           <a href="www.youtube.com"><li>Menu 4</li></a>
           <a href="www.youtube.com"><li>Menu 5</li></a>
               <a href="www.youtube.com"><li>Menu 6</li></a>
           <a href="www.youtube.com"><li>Menu 7</li></a>
               <a href="www.youtube.com"><li>Menu 8</li></a>
            </ul>
         </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

bonus:

I'm also having trouble getting Menu 1 - Menu 4 on top of Menu 5 - Menu 8 (horizontally, centered)

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borders are applied to the box that the element creates in the page, so it will also continue to the edge of any padding you have applied.

If you just want the text underlined, use `text-decoration: underline;`

Also, **your markup is invalid.** `<ul>` can only contain `<li>` as it's immediate children. Move your hyperlinks inside the list elements.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu 6</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu 7</a></li>
   <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu 8</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine after adjusting the <li>'s and <a>'s!

Comment: @user1968801 NP. I would suggest, if you are a little light on what constitutes valid HTML, that you consider heading over to http://reference.sitepoint.com/html or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML - both are good references for learning most of what you need to know for the basics of web development.

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
    margin-right: 28px;
    width: 135px;
}
```

Since the `a` contains an `li`.  The underline **is** under the `a` as it should be, since the full size of the `li`, including margin is within the `a`.